# Let $h(z) = g(f(z))$. If $f$ and $h$ are non-constant holomorphic function on domains in $\mathbb C^n$, then is $g$ holomorphic?

Tags: cv.complex-variables, several-complex-variables

Suppose there exist functions $f,g,h$ such that $h(z) = g(f(z))$. If $f$ and $h$ are non-constant holomorphic function on domains in $\mathbb C^n,\, n>1$ and $g$ is continuous, then is $g$ holomorphic? We also assume that domain of $g$ is same as range of $f$ as otherwise one could define $g$ to be anything outside the range of $f$ to break the analyticity.

For the case $n = 1$, this is indeed true, however most proofs that I found (e.g https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206652/if-composition-of-one-function-and-the-other-holomorphic-function-is-holomorphic) relies on one variable techniques! It seems that the problem could be reduced to asking the same at the image of critical points of $f$.

It would be really nice to have some references.

Comment: No, consider $f(z)=e^z$, $g(z)=0$ for $z\neq 0$ and $g(0)=1$. There are some other trivial counterexamples, so some extra assumption is needed, perhaps continuity of $g$ is enough.

Comment: It would be natural for me to assume that the domain of $g$ is same as the range of $f$, I should have stated the question that way.

Comment: What about $f(z)=z^2$, $h(z)=z$?

Comment: Is $g$ assumed continuous? And can you point to some of the "various discussions"?

Comment: They gave you counterexamples, not "various discussions"!

Comment: they gave a proof here for one variable: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206652/if-composition-of-one-function-and-the-other-holomorphic-function-is-holomorphic

Comment: @https://mathoverflow.net/users/12120/michael-renardy: About the example $f(z) = z^2$ and $h(z) = z$, there does not exists a holomorphic $g$ on all of $\mathbb C$ such that $h = g\circ f$. My question assumes such a $g$ exists.

Comment: @https://mathoverflow.net/users/112641/mtyson: Here is one such discussion: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/206652/if-composition-of-one-function-and-the-other-holomorphic-function-is-holomorphic

Comment: @mathoverflow.net/users/12120/michael-renardy: I am sorry...I misunderstood your comment...you are right...I think that we need to put an assumption that $g$ is continuous to rule out this as counter example.

Comment: I think even if we drop the assumption $g$ is continuous, it will be holomorphic where $f^'$ is nonzero in $n = 1$ case...https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1397768/let-hz-gfz-if-two-of-the-three-functions-f-g-and-h-are-holomo?noredirect=1&lq=1...some such thing can probably be said as well for several variables that each partial derivative is non-vanishing and then using Hartog's theorem but probably the condition is too stringent..